# Searching in Nested MongoDB Document using Express, Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, search, mongoose, nested

I want to search the _id having stepPath = url sent from the postman. 
Below is the nested document structure

```
[
{
    "_id": "5ebf028e989a2e2628d9d3f6",
    "funnelName": "Mortgage Leads1",
    "group": "Mortgage",
    "category": "Finance",
    "funnelStep": [
        {
            "viewsStorage": [
                {
                    "_id": "5ebf028e989a2e2628d9d3f8",
                    "viewsCounter": {
                        "currentDate": "2000-12-31T18:30:00.000Z",
                        "viewsNo": 0
                    }
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5ebf028e989a2e2628d9d3f7",
            "stepType": "Advertorial",
            "stepName": "Angle Ver 1",
            "stepPath": "google12.com",
            "isTracking": true
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5ec15febb8a83019bc966932",
    "funnelName": "Mortgage Leads",
    "group": "Mortgage",
    "category": "Finance",
    "funnelStep": [
        {
            "viewsStorage": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "_id": "5ec15febb8a83019bc966933",
            "stepType": "Advertorial",
            "stepName": "Angle Ver 1",
            "stepPath": "google.com",
            "isTracking": false
        },
        {
            "viewsStorage": [
                1,
                0
            ],
            "_id": "5ec15febb8a83019bc966934",
            "stepType": "Optin",
            "stepName": "21 Day Plan",
            "stepPath": "fb.com",
            "isTracking": true
        },
        {
            "viewsStorage": [
                2,
                0
            ],
            "_id": "5ec15febb8a83019bc966935",
            "stepType": "Checkout",
            "stepName": "Checkout Ver 1",
            "stepPath": "google.com",
            "isTracking": true
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}]
```

Model of the structure I am using -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const funnel = new mongoose.Schema({
funnelName:{
    type:String,
    unique:true
},
group: String,
category: String,
funnelStep: [{
    stepType: String,
    stepName: String,
    stepPath: String,
    isTracking: Boolean,
    viewsStorage: []
}] })
mongoose.model('Funnel',funnel)
```

JSON sent from the postman -

```
{
"funnelName":"Mortgage",
"url" : "google12.com",
"user_id" : "BATR0001",
"Date": 1 }
```

Response received in postman -

```
[]
```

Get method I am using -

```
router.get('/',function(req,res){
Funnel.find({"Funnel.funnelStep.stepPath":req.body.url},function(err,funnels){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        console.log(req.body.url)
        console.log(funnels)

        return res.json(funnels) 
    }
}) })
```

Other than this get I have tried following too -

```
Funnel.find({stepPath:req.body.url},function(err,funnels){.....}
Funnel.find({stepPath:req.params.url},function(err,funnels){....}
```

None of the above is working and only returning NULL or empty array.

Can someone please assist in this how I will be able to query this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `find` method replace `Funnel.funnelStep.stepPath` by `funnelStep.stepPath`

```
Funnel.find({ "funnelStep.stepPath": req.body.url }, function (err, funnels) { 

})
```